# how to solve kendo menu issue when reduce the size of a web browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-menu

I have kendo menu( @(Html.Kendo().Menu()) in my web page.When the user reduce the size of web browser user cannot see all the menu items.How to solve this problem.Pleases reply

Comment: Please post your code, so that others can make required changes and help you out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box solution. Your user should scroll the browser to see any content which doesn't fit in.

Comment: I don't think so.. from Demo http://demos.kendoui.com/web/menu/index.html. I just changed parent control width as auto using Firebug then it work like charm.. So I think it's possible to make.. let **Rojish Varughese** post code..